# Automapper - how to map two complex collections to one destination collection object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the two distinct objects and would like to map them to one destination object. The source objects are complex objects which contain multiple child objects which would also need to be mapped. I've tried something similar to the below example but as expected, the last mapping will overwrite any previous mapping.

```
CreateMap<sourceObject, destinationObject>()
.ForMember(d => d.Addresses, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Addresses.MainAddresses))
.ForMember(d => d.Addresses, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Addresses.SomeOtherAddresses))
```

I suppose I'm looking for something like a `MapFrom().AndThenMapFrom()` method (a join or union type transformation).

I have used a custom value resolver to get around the issue but this seems to defeat the purpose of automapper in my eyes. Any other suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Collections are cleared before mapping. Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Ha, yeah I realised the hard way :)

Comment: AutoMapper.Collection might help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to concatenate in Addresses results of mappings (MainAddresses to Addresses and SomeOtherAddresses to Addresses), one solution would be

```
CreateMap<sourceObject, destinationObject>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Addresses,
        o => o.MapFrom(
            s => s.Addresses.MainAddresses
                .Cast<object>()
                .Concat(s.Addresses.SomeOtherAddresses)))
```

or

```
CreateMap<sourceObject, destinationObject>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Addresses,
        o => o.MapFrom(
            s => s.Addresses.MainAddresses
                .Cast<IAddress>()
                .Concat(s.Addresses.SomeOtherAddresses)))
```

if objects in MainAddresses and SomeOtherAddresses realize IAddress interface.

Another solution is to do it in Before/AfterMap method

```
CreateMap<sourceObject, destinationObject>()
    .BeforeMap(
        (s, d, c) =>
        {
            var mainAddresses = c.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Address>>(s.Addresses.MainAddresses);
            var someOtherAddresses = c.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Address>>(s.Addresses.SomeOtherAddresses);

            d.Addresses = mainAddresses
                .Concat(someOtherAddresses)
                .ToArray();
        })
        .ForMember(d => d.Addresses, o => o.Ignore());
```

In this case mapping for Addresses should be ignored, because we do it "manually" in BeforeMap. Unfortunately both solutions are not elegant as most of simple automapper rules.

Comment: Appreciate the solution witalego but the `MainAddresses` and `SomeOtherAddresses` objects are unfortunately not the same so I'm unable to cast or concat them :(  I really need to dissect certain properties from each and map them individually to the destination properties.

Comment: Please try second one with BeforeMap and without casting

Comment: Yes, I really should have and it worked a treat!  Much more elegant than my custom resolver. Many thanks for opening my eyes to this :)